# Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I tried re-writing my Angular app using TypeScript, but it is not working. MainController is not a function?

I am using Visual Studio's TypeScript UMD Compiler and I am trying to run this app in a Nodejs/Expressjs server I setup on my local machine.

Here is how I define my app in myApp.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Here is the controller in MainController.ts:

```
export class MainController {
    public USER_DATA: any;

    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
        //constructor
    }
}

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', MainController]);
```

This is a small piece of what the compiled JavaScript in MainController.js looks like:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        var v = factory(require, exports); if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "MyAppExports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var MainController = (function () {
        function MainController($scope) {
            var _this = this;
        }
        return MainController;
    }());
    exports.MainController = MainController;
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('MainController', ['$scope', MainController]);
});
```

And here is index.html...

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    ...
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href="#">Notifications <span class="badge">{{USER_DATA.notifications.length}}</span></a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting an error that MainController is not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting an error that MainController is not a function?

Because your file is JavaScript module because of the `export` in `export class MainController {`.

More on modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

You need a *module bundler*. There are a few options but I (and the angular 2 team) recommend webpack. Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this module system. Webpack resolved my issues! Thanks for your articles!